# SMTP server (IIS) is running but can't test it with telnet

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, smtp

I have a Windows 2003 web edition server that I can't seem to get the SMTP relay working.

BT4 shows port 25 open. When I try use telnet to test it on my desktop I get:

```
  Connecting To XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed.
```

From the server I get:

```
Microsoft Telnet> o 127.0.0.1 25
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...

Connection to host lost.
```

There isn't anything useful in the logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does NetStat show port 25 is open?  Is the SMTP service started, is there a firewall installed?

Comment: @Ed Fries -- Netstat shows SMTP, Windows Firewall is the only firewall and port 25 is open, the SMTP Virtual Server in IIS is running.

Comment: Does it allow connections from any host? What ip/hostname is it listening on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to connect using telnet.

However I ruled out iis using [smtpdiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bc1881c7-925d-4a29-bd42-71e8563c80a9&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall doesn't block connections on the loopback.
Check on the smtp interface on which IP it is listening first.

Did you try to restart the windows smtp service ? Maybe it's in an invalid state.

Comment: It's listening on (All Unassigned), and it's static IPs on port 25.

Comment: Restarting the service hasn't helped. I don't think it's in an invalid state as it relays messages.

Comment: do you have any AV on it ? Symantec & co monitor traffic on port 25 for Virus, even the desktop edition